# Group Matching Values and Finding Which Ones Are Missing an Associated Value?

Tags: sql

I need help with writing a query to generate a result that will provide me with all record numbers NOT assigned to Group D from a table structured like the below example. From the below table my desired result would be record number "3" .

```
Record_Number    Assigned_To_Group
1                    A
1                    B
1                    C
1                    D
2                    A
2                    E
2                    D
3                    A
3                    B
3                    E
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One method uses aggregation:

```
select Record_Number
from t
group by Record_Number
having sum(case when Assigned_To_Group = 'D' then 1 else 0 end) = 0;
```

Comment: This worked thank you.  I was also messing with row over and partition by.  Could this have worked here too?